# How to copy the selected text to clipboard dynamically using android webview

Tags: android, text, webview

Im using Android Webview for showing some text. I'm implementing the LongClickListener for Webview. If I am long pressing on the Webview , Im getting the callback , but how to programmatically copy the selected text to Clipboard in Android. Im trying this using the link [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24842) , But it is giving me **NoSuchMethodException**. Here is the code

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    System.out.println("long click of webview");

    Class<? extends WebView> webViewClass = mWebvView.getClass();
    java.lang.Class<WebView>[] parameterType = null;
    java.lang.reflect.Method method = null;
    try {
        method = webViewClass.getDeclaredMethod("copySelection", parameterType);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.lang.Object[] argument = null;
    try {
        method.invoke(mWebvView, argument);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Copied selection into clipboard");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can't copy the selected text or perform any operation with the selected text using java api. To perform this, you should use the Javascript function and this works great in API>= 19.

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("webView", value);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
});
```

Add this method inside your onLongClick callback.

Comment: I have tried this , but I am getting the value as "", for all selections in the onReceiveValue